# Escaping # in SASS

Tags: sass

Here's an example of a mixin I'm using:

```
@mixin gradient($from, $to, $height) {
    background-color: #{$to};
    background-image: url("/media/img/gradient/4/#{$height}/#{$from}/#{$to}/");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

The problem is that the $from and $to colors are passed to the url without the #, so a typical call looks like this:

```
@include gradient(ff00ff, 00ff00, 600);
```

and the background-color needs a hash in front of it. I want to write the line in the mixin like this:

```
background-color: ##{$to};
```

but that doesn't work... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I decided to rewrite:

```
@include gradient(ff00ff, 00ff00, 600);
```

as

```
@include gradient("#ff00ff", "#00ff00", "600");
```

which works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do something similar, and as this was the first result on Google I thought I'd add how I got around this.

I had to pass a hex colour and use the value in the class name and as a real colour. So I created an addHash function.

Here's a simple example...

```
@function addhash($input) {
  @return unquote("#" + $input);
}

@mixin setColour($colour, $textColour:"0000ff")
{
    .headerButtons .colour#{$colour}  a{
        background:addhash($colour);
        color:addhash($textColour);
    }
}
```

@include setColour("00ff00");

This outputs CSS like this...

```
.headerButtons .colour00ff00 a {
    background: #00ff00;
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

Hopefully this will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

**#{"#" + $myVar}**